# Why I am getting Errors when I run the code?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I want to calculate the fitness function for each chromosome in population, but I always get Errors when I run the code

```
population = np.random.randint(x1,y2, size=(100, 2))
def fitness_func(x1, y1):
x2  , y2  = x1 + 160 , y1 + 60
x = 0
Im = Image.open("D:\hagar\Genetic Algorithm\Project\Binary Image.png")
for i in range (x1,x2):
    for j in range (y1,y2):
        r, g, b = Im.getpixel((i,j))
        a = (r, g, b)
        x = x + int(r/255)+ int(g/255)+ int (b/255)
return x
```

I got the errors because of the following part:

```
for chromosome in population:
print(fitness_func(population[chromosome][0],population[chromosome][1]))
```

for the previous part the error message is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "d:\hagar\Genetic Algorithm\Project\GA Eye Detection.py", line 60, in 
> print(fitness_func(population[chromosome][0],population[chromosome][1]))
> IndexError: index 143 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100

I also tried to write it as:

```
for chromosome in 10:
print(fitness_func(population[chromosome][0],population[chromosome][1]))
```

and for this part the error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "d:\hagar\Genetic Algorithm\Project\GA Eye Detection.py", line 59, in 
> for chromosome in 10:
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Could you help me please?

Comment: Please show the errors.

Comment: Assuming you actually have the code indented properly (that code is not), and assuming you supply values for `x1` and `y2`, this works for me.  Note that you should use an `r` prefix for the string that contains backslashes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Iterating over a list produces the list _values_, not the list _indexes_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your first error, you should write

```
for chromosome in population:
    print(fitness_func(chromosome[0], chromosome[1]))
```

as `chromosome` is an item in `population` not an index

for your second error, you should do

```
for chromosome in range(10):
    print(fitness_func(population[chromosome][0], population[chromosome][1]))
```